# Why does making a capture group optional cause it to never match?

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to think I'm pretty good at regular expressions, but this one is stumping me. I'm trying to match a certain type of language used in National Weather Service forecast bulletins. I'm using Perl 5.16 on Windows. I have also tested using [this online regex tester](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php). Here is an example message:

`...A SEVERE THUNDERSTORM WARNING REMAINS IN EFFECT UNTIL 1130 PM CST FOR CENTRAL LAMAR COUNTY... AT 1106 PM CST...NATIONAL WEATHER SERVICE METEOROLOGISTS WERE TRACKING A SEVERE THUNDERSTORM CAPABLE OF PRODUCING PING PONG BALL SIZE HAIL...AND DESTRUCTIVE WINDS IN EXCESS OF 70 MPH. THIS STORM WAS LOCATED NEAR BAXTERVILLE MOVING EAST AT 50 MPH. THE SEVERE THUNDERSTORM WILL BE NEAR... PURVIS BY 1115 PM CST... WEST HATTIESBURG BY 1120 PM CST...`

And here is my regex:

`/A SEVERE THUNDERSTORM.+?(?<hsize>QUARTER|GOLF BALL|PING PONG BALL|HALF DOLLAR)?.+?WINDS (?:IN EXCESS OF|OVER) (?<wmph>\d+) MPH.+WAS LOCATED (?:(?<dist>\d+) MILES (?<dir>\w+) OF|(?<near>NEAR)) (?<loc>[\w ]+).+MOVING (?<mdir>\w+) AT (?<mph>\d+) MPH/`

The problem is that the `hsize` parameter always returns blank. I would like it to be optional but greedy, however it never matches. I tried making it nonoptional:

`/A SEVERE THUNDERSTORM.+?(?<hsize>QUARTER|GOLF BALL|PING PONG BALL|HALF DOLLAR).+?WINDS (?:IN EXCESS OF|OVER) (?<wmph>\d+) MPH.+WAS LOCATED (?:(?<dist>\d+) MILES (?<dir>\w+) OF|(?<near>NEAR)) (?<loc>[\w ]+).+MOVING (?<mdir>\w+) AT (?<mph>\d+) MPH/`

Which does cause it to match, which makes no sense to me. As you can see, I've already made the wildcards nongreedy, so I don't see what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change a bit of your regex to force the engine to search for the special text before resorting to match anything. Change this part of the regex:

```
.+?(?<hsize>QUARTER|GOLF BALL|PING PONG BALL|HALF DOLLAR)?
```

To:

```
(?:.+?(?<hsize>QUARTER|GOLF BALL|PING PONG BALL|HALF DOLLAR)|.+?)
```

The alternation will force the engine to exhaust all the possibility of finding a match with the special keywords (the first alternative), before go on to match anything (the 2nd alternative).

Comment: There we go, I tried something similar to that but I just couldn't figure out how to cheat the parser quite as well as you did. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 4):

```
/A SEVERE THUNDERSTORM.+?(?<hsize>QUARTER|GOLF BALL|PING PONG BALL|HALF DOLLAR)?.+?WINDS/
```

I believe the matching goes something like this:

1. Found `"A SEVERE THUNDERSTORM"`.
2. Match first `.+?` : first attempt is using an empty string.
3. Match `(?<hsize>...)?` : from this position, it can only match an empty string.
4. Match second `.+?` : first attempt is using an empty string.
5. Failed to match `"WINDS"`.  Backtrack to step 4.
6. Backtracking many times, eventually the second `.+?` matches the entire string from `THUNDERSTORM` to the next `WINDS`.

So the backtracking never goes back to step 3 or step 2.

Maybe you could capture all text between `THUNDERSTORM` and `WINDS` and run a separate regex on it later, or change one or both `.+?` to something that will NOT match the hail size descriptions.

Comment: I don't think `(?<hsize>...)?` is matched with empty string at first attempt, since `?` is also greedy.

Comment: @nhahtdh but if the first `.+?` is matched to an empty string then if `hsize` can't be matched in the text immediately after `THUNDERSTORM` it will match an empty string due to the `?`

Comment: Ah, good point.  But if the first `.+?` is empty, `(?<hsize>...)?` has no choice but to match the empty string.

Comment: Changing `(?<hsize>QUARTER|GOLF BALL|PING PONG BALL|HALF DOLLAR)?` to `(?<hsize>QUARTER|GOLF BALL|PING PONG BALL|HALF DOLLAR)` matched.

Comment: @acattle: It would be clearer if he said that no choice in `(?<hsize>...)?` group can be matched, so the only choice is empty string.

Comment: @Kenosis: Of course, it will, but OP wants it to be optional.

Comment: Your explanation makes complete sense, and for that you get an upvote,  but I'd like to use only one regex and for that the other answer works better.